# Promise.all with "nested" axios request

Tags: javascript, axios, promise

I'm facing a small problem with Promise.all and axios. I read a lot of documentation on "how to do it", but still I did not get what I want.

Basically, I want to execute multiple *axios* requests and when they **all** finished, I want to do something…

My code is:

```
async ajaxPromise() {
            let me = this;

            const someFunction = () => {
                return new Promise(resolve => {
                    setTimeout(() => resolve('222'), 100)
                })
            }

            async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
                for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
                    debugger;
                    await callback(array[index], index, array);
                }
            }

            let urlObjects = ["https://url1.com", "https://url2.com", "https://url3.com"];
            let requestArr = [];

            await asyncForEach(urlObjects, async (data) => {
                let waitForThisData = await someFunction(data);
                requestArr.push(
                    axios.get(data)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            console.log("THEN AXIOS")
                        })
                        .catch(function (response) {
                            console.log("CATCH AXIOS")
                        })
                );
            });

            
            Promise.all([
                requestArr
            ])
                .then(function (results) {
                    console.log("THEN PROMISE")
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    console.log("FINALLY PROMISE")

                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log("CATCH PROMISE")

                });
        },
```

What happens, is console.log("THEN PROMISE") is displayed **before** all the console.log("THEN AXIOS"). What I would like to do: display the console.log("THEN PROMISE") **after** the console.log("THEN AXIOS").

Where am I wrong ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try with `await Promise.all()`

Comment: `requestArr` is already an array, you don't need to wrap it in another, instead, just use `Promise.all(requestArr)`

Comment: Although, I would get rid of the `asyncForEach` and instead call both the `someFunction()` and the `axios.get()` call in parallel (if possible), by using `.map()` on `urlObjects` to map each URL to a Promise that resolves once your `someFuntion()` and `axios.get()` are complete.

Comment: @NickParsons Yes, you are right. I simplified my code and `requestArr` is a more complex structure in reality…

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal, sorry it does not work.

Comment: Did you check the *second* comment from the top? That's what's wrong.

Comment: @NickParsons Sorry, I did not look carefully the `[requestArr]`. You were right. Thank you!